# matplotlib zoomed plot window inside a main plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, insets

I am trying to plot a zoom plot inside the main plot. I was successful in running the code and getting the plots. But there was no zoom-in.

My code:

```
# create some data to use for the plot
dt = 0.001
t = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, dt)
r = np.exp(-t[:10]/0.05)               # impulse response
x = np.random.randn(len(t))
s = np.convolve(x, r)[:len(x)]*dt  # colored noise

# the main axes is subplot(111) by default
plt.plot(t, s)

# this is another inset axes over the main axes
a = plt.axes([0.2, 0.6, .2, .2])
plt.plot(t[:len(r)], r)
plt.xlim(0, 0.2)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Present output:
[image]

Comment: You should post a [mcve]. Where is this code originally from? What is the shape of your `DataFrame`?

Comment: @Alex I updated my code with reproducable example. Thanks.

Comment: Useful to know the term for this is 'inset plot' (not 'subplot'). Specifically 'zoomed inset plot'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this code:

```py
dt = 0.001
t = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, dt)
r = np.exp(-t[:10]/0.05)
x = np.random.randn(len(t))
s = np.convolve(x, r)[:len(x)] * dt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

inset_ax = ax.inset_axes([0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2])
inset_ax.plot(t[:len(r)], r)
```

Produces:
[image: Inset plot]

Crucially, the `min`/`max` of `t[:len(r)]` is `0`/`0.009` respectively. So it seems the `xlim` that you apply is what is making it seem like there is no "zoom"